# Dirichlet's Series - Convergence

Tags: number-theory, dirichlet-series, dirichlet-convolution

Calculate the expression of the following Dirichlet's series:
$$ \dfrac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\varphi(n)}{n^s} $$
$$ \dfrac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\lambda(n)}{n^s} $$
and calculate the abscisse of convergence.

I have tried to use the definition of the Zeta of Riemann function but I don't know how to prove it. Moreover, I don't know how to calculate $\sigma_0$ (the abscisse of convergence). I wish you can give me some instructions to do it. Thanks so much.

Comment: See theorem 288 and around of one of [Hardy Wright book](https://www.chrishenson.net/static/article_files/zeta/hardy_intro.pdf).

Comment: The first one is relatively easy, the second one is called the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: @reuns That's definitely not the Riemann hypothesis

Comment: @jjagmath Knowing the abscissa of convergence of $\sum_n \lambda(n) n^{-s}$ is the same as knowing the answer to the RH

Comment: Oh, I thought that you mean the identity.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2298212/find-a-dirichlet-series-for-frac-zetas-1-zetas-valid-for-res2).

Comment: The second identity follows from the Euler product.